# What is alternative GDBus API on each dbus API?

Tags: dbus, gdbus

For example, I used ***g_dbus_connection_setup_with_g_main*** function. But [Here](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-glib/dbus-glib-DBus-GLib-low-level.html#dbus-connection-setup-with-g-main) I could find that this function is deprecated. But there's no information which function can alternate the function. Where can I find that information?

Answer (score 1):

GDBus is a part of GLib (Gio), and a different thing than dbus-glib.

Docs are here: https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GDBusConnection.html